# Extracting Twitter Followers Of Specific User

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy

Might seem like a dumb question. But I am not a good coder so I am trying to figure out what I need to do in order to set up which user to extract followers list from.

```
def get_followers(screen_name):
    print('Getting Follower list of ',screen_name)
    followers = []
    followers_screenNames = []
    users = tweepy.Cursor(api.followers, screen_name='@'+screen_name, wait_on_rate_limit=True,count=200)
    for user in users.items():
        try:
            followers.append(user)
            followers_screenNames.append(user.screen_name)
        except tweepy.TweepError as e:
            print("Going to sleep:", e)
            time.sleep(60)
    
    print('Fetched number of followers for '+screen_name+' : ',len(followers))
    return followers,followers_screenNames
```

Comment: Does this code fail or get an empty list? What do you experience?

Comment: It does. But I was trying to figure out how to specify a specific user. Like what code do I need to add to do that?

Answer (score 0):

The code seems correct: the parameter of your method must be the `screen_name`.

> The screen name, handle, or alias that this user identifies themselves with. screen_names are unique but subject to change.

See [Twitter](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/v1/data-dictionary/overview/user-object) documentation

Comment: But I am trying to figure out what code I need to write in order to set up a specific user that it should extract from.